# Instrument doesn't work in xcode 4.2 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, instruments

I am able to run the instrument on my device and can check for memory leaks but when I run the same code on simulator with instrument it hangs and my app can not go beyond splash screen. As soon as I force quit the instrument my app continues working.
 I have also tested the code using xcode 3 and instrument is working fine for both i.e for simulator as well as on device.

Anyone can suggest what I am doing wrong while running instrument on xcode 4.2 simulator.

Comment: Please make sure in simulator correct hardware version is selected on which you want to run your app. You can check this under hardware>version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying everything I have install again my xcode and its now properly working.